# Spring Cloud config server encryption decryption

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I am using the below command to encryot the password.
 curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" lonrs03668:8888/encrypt -d Simple12$jedi

after decryting the password, the value after $ sign getting lost and it is only returning the Simple12.

The issue is that if string contains the $ sign it is not encrypting/decrypting correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is working for me by adding \ before $ .

curl  -u root:s3cr3t -H "Content-Type: text/plain" lonrs03668:8888/encrypt --data-ascii Simple12\$jedi.

Answer (score 0):

Try `curl -H 'content-type: text/plain' localhost:8888/encrypt --data-raw 'your password'`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)